# Entity Framework Core 3.1 not working with already defined snake case database(sql server) schema

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, naming-conventions, ef-fluent-api

I have an exiting database and I wanted to perform crud operations on it. I am using asp.net core 3.1
web api. All my database tables are defined in snake case naming convention e.g my_table_name
during fetching the records I get the exception

Error: {Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlErrorCollection}
Message: Invalid column name 'my_table_nameID'.

This occurs only when I use Include statement in my query e.g
var temp = _sampleParentTableService.Queryable().Include(x => x.SampleChildTable).FirstOrDefault();

I tried to create 2 table Parent Table and child table with camel case naming convention e.g "MyTableName" and then used include statement and it works fine but when I tried to use same query with other table with snake case naming convention it throws an error.

Note: Relationship exists with the my_parent_table with my_child_table and column already exists in db with foreign key relationship e.g (pk ID ---> fk UserID) but Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore Include statement does not find the column and create one "my_parent_table_nameID" which does not exists.

Tried to search on web and find some articles pointing to the extensions for code first migrations
I can not use migrations because most of my db relationships are mapped manually.

Also tried finding solution for "Invalid column name" and tried all workarounds e.g model annotations [ForiegnKey] etc.

found out that whenever we declare virtual ICollections<my_parent_table> link query tries to find pk fk relationship and if not found it tries to create one with default convention "OtherTableID"

also tried

modelBuilder.Entity().Ignore(t => t.OtherTableID);

resulting  Invalid column name "OtherTableID1" exception

so I am assuming that problem is not with columns but with table names.

Expecting any solution or any middle ware that allow me to fetch records and allows me to perform crud operation on already defined database with snake case naming convention.

Comment: Not what you asked for so ignore at will, but .NET Core 3.1 and EF Core 3.1 are only [supported until December 13, 2022](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/platform/support/policy/dotnet-core) so may not be the best version for new development.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson you are right but it is a client's requirement.